# How to push items in JSON Object array in react?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, setstate

I have my REACT JS client side and using PHP APIs to fetch data. Im fetching the JSON Object array from API call, in the following format:

```js
{
    "records": {
        "Master Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "43",
                "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                "Price": "4500",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "45",
                "Name": "Lights",
                "Price": "2300",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives"
            }
        ],
        "Repair Solutions": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "47",
                "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                "Price": "1500",
                "VendorID": "60",
                "CompanyName": "Repair Solutions"
            }
        ],
        
         "FiveStar Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "51",
                "Name": "Brakes",
                "Price": "234",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "53",
                "Name": "Clutch",
                "Price": "999",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives"
            },
              {
                "SparePartID": "55",
                "Name": "LED",
                "Price": "288",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

From API response, I want to save the above response data (NAME and PRICE) in this.state of **myrecords[]** (which is empty initially)  Plus I also want to push some more items to this above JSON, like for each **SPAREPART** I want to add "**Quantity**" and "**TotalPrice**" items for each data.

Im trying to use **.push** method to add these Quantity & TotalPrice for each data item. here is my REACT API call where I m fetching data and saving it by **setState** of **myrecords[]** and pushing more items in it but IT DOESN'T WORK and shows ERROR msg. please **HELP** ME how to PUSH the items correctly.

```js
axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/show_cart.php', arr,
     {
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    } )
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data.records);

      let myItems = [];
    response.data.records.forEach((item) => {
      myItems.push({SparePartID: item.SparePartID,
         Name: item.Name,
         Price: item.Price,

         Quantity: 1,
         totalPrice: item.Price});
        })

      this.setState({
              myrecords: myItems
           })
        })
     .catch(error => {
     if (error) {
       console.log("REACT Error. Cannot show cart items");  }
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your object to array and foreach it

```
let myItems = [];
let result = Object.entries(response.records).map(( [k, v] ) => ({ [k]: v }));
    result.forEach((item) => {
      var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
      item[key].forEach((sub)=>{
      myItems.push({SparePartID: sub.SparePartID,
         Name: sub.Name,
         Price: sub.Price,

         Quantity: 1,
         totalPrice: sub.Price});
        })
});
```

```js
let response = {
    "records": {
        "Master Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "43",
                "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                "Price": "4500",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "45",
                "Name": "Lights",
                "Price": "2300",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives"
            }
        ],
        "Repair Solutions": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "47",
                "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                "Price": "1500",
                "VendorID": "60",
                "CompanyName": "Repair Solutions"
            }
        ],
        
         "FiveStar Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "51",
                "Name": "Brakes",
                "Price": "234",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "53",
                "Name": "Clutch",
                "Price": "999",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives"
            },
              {
                "SparePartID": "55",
                "Name": "LED",
                "Price": "288",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives"
            }
        ]
    }
}

let myItems = [];
let result = Object.entries(response.records).map(( [k, v] ) => ({ [k]: v }));
    result.forEach((item) => {
      var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
      item[key].forEach((sub)=>{
      myItems.push({SparePartID: sub.SparePartID,
         Name: sub.Name,
         Price: sub.Price,

         Quantity: 1,
         totalPrice: sub.Price});
        })
});

        
        console.log(myItems);
```

Comment: It works fine. but for separate handling of SpareParts by each Supplier separately I want the data in JSON Object format.   So How do I CONVERT this **array** back to my **JSON Object** format? Or is there any way that I PUSH items without converting it into Array?

Comment: you still keep old object, push method only use for array

Comment: ok but now when I console.log(myItems) it shows an array not object.

Comment: what object format do you want? you can use myItems[0] as object?

Comment: I want the object format I  mentioned in very beginning of question. Like all items are grouped by their suppliers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192747/discussion-between-yellowminion-and-hien-nguyen).